# For Loop on Windows Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am doing some batch practice and I am trying to do a loop to go backwards and count the numbers from 110 to 100, but only the even numbers. I almost got it to work, but for some reason totalCount is not updating every time the for loop goes around. At the end it prints the total as `100` which is simply the last number of the loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
::echo off
setlocal enableextensions
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a totalCount = 0

for /l %%x in (110, -2, 100) do (
   set /a totalCount = %totalCount% + %%x
)

echo total is %totalCount%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `%totalCount%` to `!totalCount!`. Therefore, the code should look like this:

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a totalCount = 0

for /l %%x in (110, -2, 100) do (
   set /a totalCount = !totalCount! + %%x
)

echo total is !totalCount!
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several *correct* ways to do this and one *wrong* way. The bad way is this:

```
for /l %%x in (110, -2, 100) do (
   set /a totalCount = %totalCount% + %%x
)
```

Because `%totalCount%` is expanded *just once*, before the `for` is executed, so the value of the sum is always 0 plus each term.

One possible solution is use Delayed Expansion as Dale suggested:

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a totalCount = 0

for /l %%x in (110, -2, 100) do (
   set /a totalCount = !totalCount! + %%x
)

echo total is %totalCount%
```

This way, the value of `!totalCount!` is correctly replaced in each `for` cycle. However, this is not needed either, because `set /A` command takes the *current* value of the variables by itself each time it is executed:

```
echo off

set /a totalCount = 0

for /l %%x in (110, -2, 100) do (
   set /a totalCount = totalCount + %%x
)

echo total is %totalCount%
```

Moreover, `set /A` command have a way to *increment a variable* that don't even requires to write its name, so the matter of this discussion completely dissapear:

```
echo off

set /a totalCount = 0

for /l %%x in (110, -2, 100) do (
   set /a totalCount += %%x
)

echo total is %totalCount%
```